# How to insert data by generating the primary key automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access, ado.net

I want to insert data generating the primary key automatically i dont know how can i generate it

There are 17 columns the first column contains primary key the second column starts from Name.

I am getting a error while I'm executing a ExecuteNonQuery().

The error is:

> Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

Obviously i know why i am getting this error its because I am inserting data for 16 columns not for the 17 but

I don't know how to insert a command by generating a primary key.

the primary key column is first and its name is CustomerId.

The code i am using is

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into realtimedata values('" + Name+ "','" + Symbol+ "','" + D + "','" + Green + "','" + GB + "','" + GS + "','" + GBIntraBuy + "','" + GBTR1Buy + "','" + GBTR2Buy + "','" + GBTR3Buy + "','" + GBIntraSell + "','" + GBTR1Sell + "','" + GBTR2Sell + "','" + GBTR3Sell + "','" + GRSTL + "','" + Red + "');", con);
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select CustomerId from realtimedata where (SecSym='" + Symbol + "')order by CustomerId", con);
temp = 0;
try
{
    object count = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    if ((count == "") || (count == null) )
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (temp > 0)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("One Record Added");
        }
        else
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Record not added");
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    // con.Close();
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: _"generating the primary key automatically"_. Don't. How are you going to handle concurrency? What if two users request a key at the same time? You'll be spending a lot of time reinventing the wheel. Please, for the love of God and the two kittens he otherwise kills, just use an autonumber column or explain _really_ clear why you think you can't use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert statement needs to be more explicit. You need specify which fields are receiving which values.

```
"insert into realtimedata(column1, column2, ... ,columnN) values('" + Name+ "','" + Symbol+ "','" + D + "','" + Green + "','" + GB + "','" + GS + "','" + GBIntraBuy + "','" + GBTR1Buy + "','" + GBTR2Buy + "','" + GBTR3Buy + "','" + GBIntraSell + "','" + GBTR1Sell + "','" + GBTR2Sell + "','" + GBTR3Sell + "','" + GRSTL + "','" + Red + "');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the errors states that

```
INSERT INTO (number of fields here)
VALUES (is not equal to number here)
```

Or don't insert primary key, create it as [AutoNumber](http://www.google.com/search?q=access+AutoNumber+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

In MsAccess, open the table in design view, and Make the first column an "***AutoNum***" Column

Comment: Then you may not have done it properly.  That is the setting or attribute thaty affects this behavior in Access.